# LG NetCast Smart TV "cannot access this service"

Tags: smart-tv, lg

I have a very simple app. I don't get any errors in a browser or in the emulator, but when trying on the TV all I get is "cannot access this service".

```
<body>
<label class="Label_1" lge-type="Label">Hello World</label>
<div>
    <object type="application/x-netcast-broadcast"
        id="broadcast"
        width="500"
        height="400"
    >
    </object>
</div>
</body>
```

There is nothing about what this error means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with the app, but the way I loaded it into the LG Store was wrong.

I was making a zip of the files on the computer and uploading that instead of using the "File" -> "Export [App Name]"